# How to assign value to __func__ in C?

Tags: c, char, constants, variable-assignment

For some reason, I have not found a direct answer to this question anywhere in the documentation.

My friend says I can directly use `__func__` and assign to it, without actually declaring it.

The [documentation](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2004/n1642.html) says:

```
1. The identifier __func__ shall be implicitly declared by the translator as
if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the
declaration

    static const char __func__[] = "function-name";

appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.
```

So, does that mean, I should declare it every time I begin a function with `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";` instead of `strcpy(__func__, "function-name");` because it has already been declared and will be handled by the compiler?

I'm sorry if this sounds like a basic question, but I'm mighty confused!

Comment: Well, you can't assign to it since it's a const array...

Comment: The docs mention the *translator* who is assigning the string. Why do you assume to be the *translator*?

Comment: Yes, I realise how stupid I sound when I read it now.

Comment: No; you don't declare it — it is implicitly declared by the translator (meaning 'compiler').  No; you can't modify it — it is declared `const`.  Interestingly, neither GCC nor Clang let you redefine `__func__` in an inner block inside a function, but the error it gives is not very coherent (```error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘__func__’```, but change `__func__` to `__function__` and the code compiles). OTOH, you shouldn't be trying that sort of trick anyway.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Probably gcc somehow replaces `__func__` with a string literal, rather than a declared variable. You get the same compiler error if you write `int __func__;` as you get when writing `int "hello";`. It would seem that this string literal has the type `const char*` though, and not `char*` like a regular string literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to declare or define it. It's implicitly available to your code inside a function definition.

```
void func_with_fancy_name() 
{
  puts(__func__); // Will print the function name
}
```

Assigning is a different matter. You cannot do that. The `const` specifier in the "as if" declaration should deter you.

Comment: `printf("%s", __func__);` would be better just in case name-mangling stuck a `%` into the function name.

Comment: @KenY-N - Yeah, I was contemplating that. Went with `puts` instead on second thought.

Comment: @KenY-N I don't believe name mangling is allowed to happen before `__func__` is assigned a value by the compiler, or otherwise the compiler wouldn't follow the standard requirements. `__func__` must give the exact identifier name of the function.

Answer (score 2):

> *My friend says I can directly use `__func__` [...]*

Yes, you can. Notice this part

> [...] shall be **implicitly declared by the translator as
>   if**, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the
>   declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, [...]

So, you don't need to be explicit.

> .. *and assign to it,*

No, you cannot. It is a constant.

Comment: I just read the line in the documentation again, it suddenly makes so much sense now! I feel like an idiot :/

Comment: such 'fast read' of the documentation has happened to us all (more than once)